# Code for alert action of UILocalNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

```
UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
notif.fireDate = [self.datePicker date];
notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

notif.alertBody = @"Did you forget something?";
notif.alertAction = @"Show me";
```

if the user clicks on "showme" the app should open and he should get the alert.
Where should i write this code?and if possible someone please give me a little bit of code

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will get the notification about the *UILocalNotification* in two places depending on app's state at the time the notification is fired.

1.In **application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** method, if the app is neither running nor in the background.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    ...
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];  
    if (localNotif) {       
        // Show Alert Here
    }
    ...
}
```

2.In **application:didReceiveLocalNotification:** method if the app is either running or in background. Its almost useless to show the alert when the app is already running. So you have to show the alert only when the app was in background at the time the notification fired. To know if the app is resuming from background use the *applicationWillEnterForeground:* method.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

    isAppResumingFromBackground = YES;
}
```

Using this you can show the alert in *didReceiveLocalNotification:* method only when the app is resuming from background.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    if (isAppResumingFromBackground) {

        // Show Alert Here
    }
}
```

You can simply omit the *if-condition* if you want to show the alert view all the time the notification is fired regardless of the app's state.

Comment: thanks the alert is working fine now.....But the text to be displayed in that alert is from other view controller and why is it not working??.'application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
 
    NSString *reminderText = [notification.userInfo      objectForKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
 [viewController showReminder:reminderText];

Comment: show reminder is the method i wrote in the other view controller but i dont know why its not getting called

Comment: nice way to deal with local notif. Do you suggest any place to set `isAppResumingFromBackground` to `YES` ? Some place it will be called after `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` but will be called in any kind of case the app resumes.

Answer (score 4):

Add a function which we will call on the touch of the button inside the YourViewController.h file and then give the body to that function in the YourViewController.m file

```
-(void)Trigger_LocalNotification
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    UILocalNotification *_localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

      //setting the fire dat of the local notification
    _localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];


    //setting the time zone
    _localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    //setting the message to display
    _localNotification.alertBody = @"Did you forget something?";

    //default notification sound
    _localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    //displaying the badge number
    _localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1;

    //schedule a notification at its specified time with the help of the app delegate
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:_localNotification];

}
```

The first line of the code removes all the local notification from the system if they are declared. In the second line I am initializing the UILocalNotification variable and in the third line I am using the fireDate property to set the time when this local notification will trigger and as you can see that the notification will be triggered after 5 seconds.

The soundName is a property of the UILocalNotification class which is used to play a sound when the notification is triggered and when the app firing this local notification is not active then in that case a alert box will pop up with the default notification sound and the alert message is written in using the property alertBody. The last line of the code will attach this notification with the system.

> make sure to attach this function with the button touch up inside
>   event

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(Trigger_LocalNotification) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now select the App Delegate.m file of your project and create the object of this class (YourViewController)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    YourViewController *obj = [[YourViewController alloc]init];
    [self.window addSubview:obj.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Run the application and when the app is launched in the simulator then quickly press the home button to see the alert box of the local notification after 5 sec.

I hope that this answer has helped you out in learning how to implement UILocalNotification.

Comment: What about the alert action??? in my case if the user clicks on that action button the application should come to foreground and the user should see an alert(not the one with alertbody and alert action)

Answer (score 0):

there is a delegate method called didreceivelocalnotification.You have to write this in the app delegate.And when the user clicks then this delegate method will be going to call.So write any code in the didreceivelocalnotifaction method.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
}
```

Comment: - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
 
 application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
 NSString *reminderText = [notification.userInfo
         objectForKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
 [viewController showReminder:reminderText];
}

Comment: I have written this but i dont know why this showReminder method is not getting called

Comment: check whether that method is calling or not?

Comment: ya that didreceivelocalnotification method is getting called but no alert is showing up

Comment: check like this.remove the if condition.Then check whether it is coming or not

Comment: but i didnt use any if condition there