# How can I tell if a local notification was fired while the application was in the background?

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to run specific code if a local notification was fired while the application was in the background and has now entered the foreground. One way to do this is to get the badge count, is there a better way?

Answer (score -2):

Check out the docs at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

Your App Delegate can detect notifications when the app is in the background

```
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {

    NSString *itemName = [notif.userInfo objectForKey:ToDoItemKey]

    [viewController displayItem:itemName];  // custom method

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber-1;

}
```

Comment: That only gets called if the application is in the foreground.

Comment: Check the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008235/code-for-alert-action-of-uilocalnotification - it is the same issue. He uses a local bool to determine if he is in the background or not from the applicationWillEnterForeground function.