# UINotification customisation

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, notifications

How to customise the uinotification like as in the image[image]

Can any give me some reference or tutorial?Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008235/code-for-alert-action-of-uilocalnotification

Comment: http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-scheduling-local-notifications-using-a-singleton-class/

Comment: @RachelGallen I don't see how those links relate to the question of customization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple does not allow third-party developers to do this.

Comment: Then how the yahoo widgets are like in the image

Comment: Apple built weather and stock information into Notification Center, but they don't allow third party developers to do the same. Yahoo provides the data Apple uses in those apps.

Comment: one doubt `http://www.andyibanez.com/2012/02/20/create-a-notification-center-widget-for-ios/` .wether apple will accept when we implement as like the above link

Comment: Using private APIs is grounds for rejection, and I'm certain that uses private APIs, so unfortunately it won't be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Local Weather Notification

[WeatherKit](https://github.com/rnystrom/WeatherKit)